# Python average slope

Tags: python, average

```
def mean_slope(f, a, b):
 '''
  Write a python function which returns the average slope of a function f within a range a and b.a < b
'''


print(mean_slope(some_func, 2, 8))
```

How to write a python function which returns the average slope of a function f within a range a and b.a < b

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should probably elaborate on your question, show what you have tried, and provide an example input and output if you want answers for your question. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @sticky Please consider accepting my answer by clicking the check-mark next to the answer if it solves your problem. This is completely optional and no love would be lost otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

This defines a function `mean_slope` that, given a function of one variable `f`, returns the average slope of `f` over the interval `[a, b]` with `a < b`. This is tested with the function `square`.

```
def mean_slope(f, a, b):
    """
    given a function of one variable f, returns average slope of f over
    [a, b], a < b
    """
    return (f(b) - f(a)) / (b - a)

def square(x):
    return x * x

print(mean_slope(square, 2, 8))
```

Output

```
10.0
```